# Gerar relatório personalizado com Python

Tags: python, ireport

alguém já trabalhou ou já viu alguém desenvolver relatórios personalizados com python?

Por exemplo, no Java conseguimos criar um relatório de forma fácil com o iReport que possui modelos de exemplos e criação de novos templates com a facilidade de arrastar e soltar, preenchendo com dados em tempo real ou de um banco de dados.

Estou querendo uma única linguagem pra fazer so tudo com ela, análise de dados e criação de software desktop com banco de dados e etc...

A questão é que tudo é muito fácil no java, mas análise de dados e aprendizagem de máquinas não é, ai resolvi migrar para o python mas se eu não conseguir gerar relatórios personalizados facilmente não vou migrar, infelizmente.

Lembrando que não quero soluções como o Jupyter, quero na verdade que o meu próprio software gere o relatório em pdf sempre que eu mandar.

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Não sou muito da area, mas a galera costuma usar "pandas" para analise massiva de dados depois usam o "jinja2" para gerar relatorios em html. Depois você poderia utilizar alguma lib ou software para converter o html em pdf.

Comment: Tem razão Samuel, ponha seu comentário como resposta que marco, pois foi uma excelente direção, considero a resposta. Obrigado!